# Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB' not found app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php magento using zend library

Tags: php, magento, pdf, zend-framework

this code:

```
$page  = $this->newPage();
```

has been replaced by this:

```
$pdf->pages[] = $pdf->newPage('4:6:');
```

but this results in:

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB' not found app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php

Please tell how can I reduce page size of a pdf in magento?

Comment: what $this ? Where the code come from ?

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB' not found seems like a syntax error in a require/require_once // or your include_path is misconfigured

Comment: I have extended this class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Shipment

Answer (score 10):

Actually there is no class **Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB**. Its **Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb**. Check your code and replace **Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB** with **Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb**